# Partial Background on iOS Mobile Safari

Tags: ios5, css, mobile-safari

Take a look at the screenshot below. My div with the ID of #top is only covering a portion of the screen on iOS where on my computer it is full width. Full width is the expected behavior.

You can see the source live at https://resipsalaw.com

Any ideas on why this is happening?

[image: Partial Width Background]

Comment: Does only setting the viewport not work <meta content='width=device-width' name='viewport'>

Comment: I mean if you set the viewport width as device-width, the background which has repeat-x should stretch to 100% of the device-width (think it is 480px for iPhone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
body {
  width:100%;
  min-width: 1060px;
}
```

Comment: Good question, just had that same issue. Even better really simple answer, loving it.